# How do mobs with "Shielding" work?

Tags: diablo-iii

Some Elite/Champion mobs have a "Shielding" modifier where they bubble themselves for a while.  How does the shield work; does it absorb a fixed amount of HP?  Are they totally immune (from damage and effects) while encased?

Answer (score 4):

"Monsters imbued with the Shielding trait have the ability to temporarily make themselves immune to all forms of damage". To quote diablo wiki.

It also just lasts for a fixed period of time, depending on how many people are in your party it can go from 3-5 seconds of invulnerability from all damage types.

Answer (score 1):

Monsters with shielding are immune to all effects while shielding is active, including damage and - irritatingly - crowd control effects such as Frost Nova. They're surrounded by a faint green glow while shielded, and the duration lasts increasingly longer depending on your current difficulty.

Comment: Just a quick note. Shielded mobs are in fact not imune to all types of cc. Take for instance monks blinding flash. It blids shielded mobs for the normal amount of time.